# HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL Tomcat

Tags: java

I'm developing a web app using the following code, but I end up with an error:

After i clicked submit button in html, the error 405 occurred. Please help check where i should make changes..Thanks alot

Comment: You have defined doPost() <-- POST.

Comment: Don't hand-write servlets. Use a framework such as Spring MVC that does that all for you.

Comment: Hello New User, please tell us the following to help us answer you question:
1) What is the error you are getting?
2) Please limit the code to the relevant portions by providing a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example (SSCCE, http://www.sscce.org/)

Answer (score 2):

> HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL Tomcat

This cannot be any clearer.

You are sending a GET request to a server that has registered a `UploadImage` servlet that only handles POST requests.

In this case, it inherits `HttpServlet#doGet(..)` which returns 405 Not Supported status code.

Either send a POST request or have your `Servlet` override the `doGet(..)` method.

Comment: in my html, im using method post,but i dont know why the error is about method get.Please help

Comment: @user3550919 Show us the request you make. You can edit your question to add details.

Comment: @user3550919 Show us how you make the requests. Right now, you've only shown your servlet mappings.

Comment: @user3550919 Try opening up your browser's network console. When you click the submit button, what requests does the console say is sent?

Comment: tried.But it's blank and didnt show anything.What else should i try?

Comment: @user3550919 Take a picture and show us. I doubt it's blank. It should show the path of the request you made. If you select it, it should show the request headers, response headers and body.